# How to pass a Vue prop into a child component while using v-for?

Tags: vue.js, v-for, prop

When passing a Vue prop into a child component while using v-for, the child component appears on the page but does not display the prop. There are no errors present in the browser console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The component passing the prop:

```html
<template>
    <div class="col" ref="participants-window">
        
    <div>
        <user 
        v-for="(username, index) in participants"
        v-bind:username="username"
        v-bind:index="index"
        > </user>
    </div>     
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['participants'],
    
    data() {
      return {
         show: true,
         username: null
     }      
},
    
    mounted() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
},

watch: {
    messages() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }
},

methods: {
    scrollToBottom() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$refs['participants-window'].scrollTop = this.$refs['participants-window'].scrollHeight;
        });
    }
},
} 

</script>

<style scoped>

.col {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

The component receiving the prop:

```html
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
  <b-button id="tooltip-button-2" variant="primary">{{ username }}</b-button>
  <b-tooltip show target="tooltip-button-2">tooltip</b-tooltip>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

 props: ['username']

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
         show: true,
         username: null
     }      
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: use `v-bind:key="index"` as a prop for `user` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put props inside the export default. Also you can't have a prop and data with the same name.

This is what you can do

```
export default {
    props: ['username'],

    data() {
      return {
         show: true
     }      
  }
```

You also don't need the data username in your first component, the username will pass to user if defined in participants

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple `username`:

1.`username` in iterating the `participants` prop.

2. `username` variable in `data`

It seems that the `template` part is trying to use your data part which is null.

You need to remove the second one. So your data will become like this:

```js
export default {
    data() {
      return {
         show: true,
     }      
}
```

Also try to add a `key` prop to your `user` element too. It has been required to use `key` in latest version of vue.

So your template would be like below:

```
<user 
        v-for="(username, index) in participants"
        v-bind:username="username"
        v-bind:index="index"
        v-bind:key="`user-${index}`"
/>
```